Xml serialization not working with hashset c#
I have a xml which is using the following structure
<projects>
  <project>
     <id>1</id>
     <pnames>110988</pnames>
  </project>
  <project>
    <id>1</id>
    <pnames>10112;12121;21323;13233</pnames>
  </project>
</projects>

I am using
[xmlelement]
 public HashSet<string> Pnames {get; set;}

but error occurs 'Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''.'

Which Xml Serializer and how do you call it? How did you try telling the XmlSerializer that pnames, that looks simply like a string and not like an Array Type, is a Hashset? It can't guess that. XmlElement does not do that.

pnames is not a hash set.  It is number string separated by a semicolon.

i know its a number of string but can we get the string and then add the semicolon separated values in hashset?
